# onClick redirect to a side after 5 sec

Tags: php, javascript, redirect

How do i add to a button so after i press it. it will redirect me to a side after like 5 sec?
I have tried so much different stuff but it is not working for me...
It need to be a onClick function (javascript).

HTML:

```
    <html>
<head>

<style type="text/css">
#save_first { display: none; }
#save_second { display: none; }
#save_third { display: none; }
</style>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://mctheblitz.com/servers/js/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/custom.js"></script>

</head>
<body>

<input type="button" value="Save" onClick="save();"/>
<div id="save_first"></div><div id="save_second"></div>
<?php



</body>
</html>
```

Javascipt:

```
function save() {

    $('#save_first').html('Validating...');
    $('#save_first').fadeIn(1);
    $('#save_first').delay(2000);
    $('#save_first').fadeOut(300);
    $('#save_second').html('Successfully log in!');
    $('#save_second').hide();
    $('#save_second').delay(2350);
    $('#save_second').fadeIn(0);
}
```

Tnx for help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should redirect you to another site:

window.location = "http://www.yoururl.com";

Answer (score 0):

You can basicly just create a function with setInterval(code,millisec) to 5000. and replace the code with a function u have.

```
<html>
<body>

<input type="text" id="clock">
<script language=javascript>

function fiveseconds() {
    setInterval(function(){clock()},5000);
}


function clock() {
    alert("pow");
}
</script>

<button onclick="fiveseconds()">Stop</button>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: its just a base.. you need to set some sort of block after 5 secs.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're using jQuery. You can do it like this:

```
$('#id-of-button').click(function() {
    setTimeout(function () { location.href='http://url.tld'; }, 5000);
    $(this).unbind();
});
```

**Demo**

[Try before buy](http://jsfiddle.net/X878M/)

Comment: oki so i did this `$('#redirect').click(function() {
    setTimeout("location.href='index.php'", 4651);
    $(this).unbind();
});
` and this `<input id="redirect" type="button" value="Save" onClick="save();"/>` **then nothing happend** @insetusernamehere

Comment: @user2733334 Sorry I forgot to put it into a closure. I've updated the answer and added a demo.